# I don't understand the error. (android build error cordova)

Tags: java, cordova, gradle

Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=undefined (recommended setting)
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\uslua\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk (DEPRECATED)
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Subproject Path: app

Configure project :CordovaLibProject evaluation failed including an error in afterEvaluate {}. Run with --stacktrace for details of the afterEvaluate {} error.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'C:\Users\uslua\akrida\myapp\platforms\android\CordovaLib\build.gradle' line: 41
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':CordovaLib'.
  Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.github.dcendents.android-maven']
  Configuration with name 'testImplementation' not found.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BU�LD FAILED in 10s

C:\Users\uslua\akrida\myapp\platforms\android\gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
Project evaluation failed including an error in afterEvaluate {}. Run with --stacktrace for details of the afterEvaluate {} error.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'C:\Users\uslua\akrida\myapp\platforms\android\CordovaLib\build.gradle' line: 41
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':CordovaLib'.
  Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.github.dcendents.android-maven']
  Configuration with name 'testImplementation' not found.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BU�LD FAILED in 10s

> I try everyhing. I've uploaded jdk and gradle. cordova and sdk updated. recently it was working smoothly

Answer (score 0):

Since the error message indicates that `Configuration with name testImplementation not found` I think you're most likely running the Gradle build with the wrong Gradle version. Please upgrade to [the lastest Gradle version](https://gradle.org/releases/) and try again.

Comment: I've uploaded it based on the latest gradle. Cordova can't see him, I think. gradle -v return : Welcome to Gradle 5.4.1!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55601018/how-to-fix-build-gradle-problem-in-a-cordova-project