# When trying to compile Cordova, an error like this occurs

Tags: android, cordova, cmd

C:\Users\BNA\merhaba>cordova build android
Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=undefined (recommended setting)
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\BNA\AppData\Local\Android\sdk (DEPRECATED)
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Subproject Path: app

> Configure project :CordovaLib
>   Project evaluation failed including an error in afterEvaluate {}. Run with --stacktrace for details of the afterEvaluate {} error.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'C:\Users\BNA\merhaba\platforms\android\CordovaLib\build.gradle' line: 41
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':CordovaLib'.

  > Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.github.dcendents.android-maven']
  >   Configuration with name 'testImplementation' not found.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
C:\Users\BNA\merhaba\platforms\android\gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
Project evaluation failed including an error in afterEvaluate {}. Run with --stacktrace for details of the afterEvaluate {} error.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'C:\Users\BNA\merhaba\platforms\android\CordovaLib\build.gradle' line: 41
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':CordovaLib'.

  > Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.github.dcendents.android-maven']
  >   Configuration with name 'testImplementation' not found.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s

Answer (score 0):

1. Goto AppFolder/platforms/Android you will find build.gradle file.
2. Open the file using any text editor and replace:

   dependencies {
   classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'
   }

with:

```
dependencies {
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
```

}

Comment: you can also check this link if that didn't work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55601018/how-to-fix-build-gradle-problem-in-a-cordova-project